# Delay accept() in Python socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

Using Sockets in Python3, can I:

- `listen()` on a socket
- when I receive a connection on that socket: `connect()` to another server
- If the connection is successful, `accept()` the first connection, else close the socket

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: That's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accept` is the way for the server application to know both that some client has connected and to get a socket to this client. But `accept` does not actually create the connection to the client. This connection will already be established by the OS just because the server socket was changed to the `listen` state. `accept` only provides the already established TCP connection to the application.

So you need to actually call `accept` first to even know that there is some client connecting to the server. If you don't want this client just `close` the accepted connection.

Note that some OS have  the concept of [accept filters](https://wiki.freebsd.org/200705NetworkCabal?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=bsdcan07_acceptfilters.pdf), where connections can be checked inside the kernel before they are returned by `accept`. But even in this case the TCP connection is first established, and from the perspective of the client there is not much of a difference where the established connection is actually closed, i.e. OS kernel or server application.